# Table of contents blank

Tags: r, r-markdown, presentation, beamer

I am trying to create a beamer presentation using R Markdown. Everything was fine until I updated the software to latest versions of R and RStudio. Now my Table of Contents do not appear (blank page instead) and the words "Section 1", "Section 2" ... etc appear above every Section title on my presentation.

I tried with toc: true, toc: false, changing theme, even creating a new R Markdown beamer from scratch but nothing worked.

````
---
title: "TITLE"
subtitle: "Subtitle"
author: "Guillermo Ortiz"
date: "9-oct-2019"
output: beamer_presentation
theme: "Madrid"
toc: TRUE
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

# Hello

## Goodbye

Bla bla bla bla
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see all of what you describe:  I get the section numbers showing, but the table of contents isn't blank.  The following fixes the section number issue, but it might not fix your TOC:

The problem is in the generated `.tex` file.  When you specify the theme to be "Madrid", R Markdown is putting the LaTeX line

```
\usetheme[]{Madrid}
```

into the `.tex` file.  The problem is that it gets put in after a bunch of customizations to the style (`\setbeamertemplate{section page}`, etc.) and it overrides them.

[Edited to add:]  this is actually how it should be.  You asked for Madrid, if you want something different, you should have to ask for it.  Pandoc shouldn't be overriding the theme you asked for.

There are several ways to ask for this change to the Madrid theme.  One is
to include the request in the header, by putting them in a file (e.g. `mysections.sty`) and putting this in your YAML:

```
output: 
  beamer_presentation:
    includes: 
      in_header: mysections.sty
```

The `mysections.sty` should contain something like this (the Pandoc default):

```
\setbeamertemplate{section page}{
\centering
\begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=12pt,center]{part title}
  \usebeamerfont{section title}\insertsection\par
\end{beamercolorbox}
}
```

You might want other options (e.g. `\begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=12pt,center,rounded,shadowed]`).

Comment: I fixed the section numbers problem with your answer. Thanks a lot for that. However, when I write "rounded, shadowed" in my sty file, the RMarkdown throws and error: "rounded unspecified" and "shadowed undefined".

With respect to the other issue, the TOC, I cannot seem to find the problem. It still prints a blank page instead of the TOC. I don't know why.

Comment: You might need `\begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=12pt,center,rounded=true,shadowed=true]`.  For the TOC issue, you do need to run `pdflatex` on the `.tex` file more than once; maybe your system isn't doing that for some reason.  In my case, `pandoc` appears to do it automatically.

Comment: Hello! So, I am not able to print the TOC not even with the Beamer template that comes as default. What would you think is the problem? Maybe my computer is blocking it somehow or the color of the TOC is the same as the background (unlikely since I am using Madrid theme). I am very new at this so maybe the case that latex code is wrong. Would you tell me how to run pdflatex on the .tex file more than once? or how to modify the latex code? Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't know why you're not getting it.  You can add `keep_tex: true` as an option to `beamer_presentation`, then just try processing the .tex file you produce; its .log file might contain some error messages.

Comment: I solved it changing the latex engine to xelatex instead of pdf latex. I don't know exactly why it wasn't working with pdflatex but with xelatex it worked! Thank you very much for all your comments!